# Blurry text in tooltip (ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, transform, ngx-bootstrap, translate3d

When using ngx-bootstrap, if I create a tooltip with a lot of text, the text has a slight blur.

If I inspect the element, the transform translate 3d is what seems to cause the blur.  If I turn that off, then the text sharpens...but then the tooltip positioning is lost.

```
element.style {
    will-change: transform;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translate3d(119px, -34px, 0px);
}
```

Is there a way to sharpen the text?

I tried the following, but it did not help:

```
.tooltip {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Below are sample images of tooltip with translate3d (blurry) and without (crisp).

[image: Blurry]

[image: Not blurry]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cmbj3

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cmbj3-fnhz18?file=app/basic.html

Use

```
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, though it's still blurry.

Comment: I don't see any blur can you post screen shot or what browser you are using

Comment: Sure, I just added two pictures, where I toggle the transform translate 3d.  The first picture is slightly blurry/faded, whereas the second is more crisp.

Comment: I notice blur too :(